# formally prove or disprove the following statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I formally prove or disprove the following statement about integers, if $x|y$ and $x|z$ then $x|(2y+3)z$

Comment: have you tried to write what it means that $x$ divides $y$ and $z$ and inject it into the formula $(2y+3)z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

In this type of exercise, you have to write the hypotheses correctly and try to gather all this together. To give you the intuition of the result, you can try on small numbers.

**Answer**:

Following the hypothesis
$$
\exists (k,k') \in \mathbf{N}^2, y = kx \text{ and } z = k'x
$$
Therefore
$$
(2y+3)z = (2kx + 3)(k'x) = 2kk'x^2 + 3k'x = (2kk'x + 3k')x = K x
$$
with $K = 2kk'x + 3k' \in \mathbf{N}$ so
$$
x|(2y+3)z
$$

Comment: +1 Good advice in the first sentence. I think the proof would be easier to read if you used more words and fewer logical symbols. That would not be less "formal".

Answer (score 1):

How about this statement:

> If $y$ is an integer and $x|z$ then $x|(2y+3)z$.

The first part ($x|z$) says $z$ is a multiple of $x$; we then take that multiple and multiply it by the integer $2y+3,$ obtaining again a multiple of $x.$

The fact that you are given $x|y$ is a bit of a red herring; you don't need to use that fact in the proof.
Of course if you do know that $x|y$ then you know $y$ is an integer,
so it still follows (from this and from $x|z$) that $x|(2y+3)z.$

Answer (score 0):

You have to know 2 things:

if $a|b$ and $a|c$, then a divides any linear combination between b and c (a|b+c)

if $a|b$, then $a|bc$ for all integer c

Here we want to prove that $x$ divides $(2yz + 3z)$, and we have $x|y$ and $x|z$:

$x$ then divides $2yz$ and $3z$ seperately, and their linear combination as well.

So formally:

$x|y \Longrightarrow x|2yz$

$x|z \Longrightarrow x|3z$

$x|2yz$ and $x|3z \Longrightarrow x|(2y+3)z$

Hope it helps

Comment: I think "have to know" here is wrong.  It's a convenience to know these, but the other answer (by Mondologie) does not rely on them.